# How to loop through list during API call?

Tags: python

I am looking to loop through about 5 stock tickers using an API. Currently I have "MSFT" as the only stock being called; however, I would like to make a stock list to return multiple responses.

For example:

```py
stock_list = ["MSFT", "AAPL", "LMD", "TSLA", "FLGT"]
```

How can I request all 5 of these stocks to the querystring to print each response? Here is what I have currently which prints only "MSFT" into a json format...

```py
import requests

#Use RapidAPI request to call info on Stocks
url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"

querystring = {"function":"GLOBAL_QUOTE","symbol": "MSFT"}


headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "KEY INSERTED HERE,
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Comment: Here is the current output:     {'Global Quote': {'01. symbol': 'MSFT', '02. open': '227.0800', '03. high': '230.0700', '04. low': '225.8000', '05. price': '225.9500', '06. volume': '30172663', '07. latest trading day': '2021-01-22', '08. previous close': '224.9700', '09. change': '0.9800', '10. change percent': '0.4356%'}}
Status Code: 200

Comment: Have you tried iterating over `stock_list`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

```
import requests

url = 'https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query'
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': '<API KEY>',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com',
}

tickers = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'LMD', 'TSLA', 'FLGT']

for ticker in tickers:
    querystring = {'function': 'GLOBAL_QUOTE', 'symbol': ticker}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(r.json())
```

You can also try pretty printing the json output using the `json` module.

```
import json

# ... your code ...

for ticker in tickers:
    # ... your code ...

    print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2))
```

Also, **you should delete your API key before its abused by anyone!** These have to be kept safe somewhere.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Nick. Will do!